# NPM Could not resolve dependency

Tags: nuxt.js

I have web app with nuxt js and when I run npm install I get endless loop from the following error [image]

I tried to delete node_modules folder, I cleaned the cache nothing works, I tried to install eslint-plugin-vue also same
so basically anything I want to do with NPM i get the same result
any suggestion

here is my package.json file

```
{
"engines": {
    "node": "16.13.0",
    "npm": "8.1.0"
},
"name": "my web app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "test": "jest --silent=false --watchAll=false --verbose=false"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.13",
    "@core-player/playcore-hls": "^0.1.1",
    "@datadog/browser-logs": "^1.26.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.13.6",
    "@saasquatch/squatch-js": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "@types/vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/composition-api": "1.1.2",
    "@vuelidate/core": "2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^3.22.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.14.0",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dompurify": "^2.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jimp": "^0.16.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
    "nuxt-webpack-optimisations": "^2.2.0",
    "rgbaster": "^2.1.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-azure-blob-upload": "0.0.6",
    "vue-core-video-player": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-fragment": "1.5.1",
    "vue-luxon": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-plyr": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-sortable": "^0.1.3",
    "vue-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuejs-localization": "^1.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.4",
    "vuetify-dialog": "^2.0.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "@nuxt/types": "2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "2.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.47.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.5.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.10",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "vue-demi": "^0.4.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-server-renderer": "2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.14"
}
```

}

Comment: Something I was looking at indicated that you may need a Node version less than 15 in order to use that library version: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-vue-argon-dashboard-pro-laravel/issues/2

Comment: @JeremyHarris I change node version to 15 but I get different error 
ERR! npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm ERR! npm WARN Found: rollup@2.70.2
npm ERR! npm WARN node_modules/rollup
npm ERR! npm WARN   dev rollup@"^2.70.2" from the root project

Comment: Try Node less than 15. Or upgrade the version of Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'